# Standalone Next App with express, next12 to next14 migration

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, build

I modified the standalone output `.next/standalone/server.js` to add a proxy server with express., but after changing the NEXT version from 12.3.0 to 14.0.4,
When I run the server with the `node server.js` command and connect to `localhost:3000`, I get a 404 error.

**ENV**
`next` 12.0.3 to 14.0.4
`nodeJs` 18.17.1
`yarn` 1.22.21

This files we were using in version 12.0.3.

server.js:

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./ca/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./ca/server.crt'),
};

// process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'
process.chdir(__dirname);
const NextServer = require('next/dist/server/next-server').default;

// Make sure commands gracefully respect termination signals (e.g. from Docker)
// Allow the graceful termination to be manually configurable
if (!process.env.NEXT_MANUAL_SIG_HANDLE) {
  process.on('SIGTERM', () => process.exit(0));
  process.on('SIGINT', () => process.exit(0));
}

const currentPort = 3000;

const nextServer = new NextServer({
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: currentPort,
  dir: path.join(__dirname),
  dev: false,
  customServer: false,
  conf: {
    env: {},
    webpackDevMiddleware: null,
    eslint: { ignoreDuringBuilds: false },
    typescript: { ignoreBuildErrors: false, tsconfigPath: 'tsconfig.json' },
    distDir: './.next',
    cleanDistDir: true,
    assetPrefix: '',
    configOrigin: 'next.config.js',
    useFileSystemPublicRoutes: true,
    generateEtags: true,
    pageExtensions: ['tsx', 'ts', 'jsx', 'js'],
    target: 'server',
    poweredByHeader: true,
    compress: true,
    analyticsId: '',
    images: {
      deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
      imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
      path: '/_next/image',
      loader: 'default',
      domains: [],
      disableStaticImages: false,
      minimumCacheTTL: 60,
      formats: ['image/webp'],
      dangerouslyAllowSVG: false,
      contentSecurityPolicy: "script-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; sandbox;",
      remotePatterns: [],
      unoptimized: false,
    },
    devIndicators: { buildActivity: true, buildActivityPosition: 'bottom-right' },
    onDemandEntries: { maxInactiveAge: 15000, pagesBufferLength: 2 },
    amp: { canonicalBase: '' },
    basePath: '',
    sassOptions: {},
    trailingSlash: false,
    i18n: null,
    productionBrowserSourceMaps: false,
    optimizeFonts: true,
    excludeDefaultMomentLocales: true,
    serverRuntimeConfig: {},
    publicRuntimeConfig: {},
    reactStrictMode: false,
    httpAgentOptions: { keepAlive: true },
    outputFileTracing: true,
    staticPageGenerationTimeout: 60,
    swcMinify: false,
    output: 'standalone',
    experimental: {
      optimisticClientCache: true,
      manualClientBasePath: false,
      legacyBrowsers: true,
      browsersListForSwc: false,
      newNextLinkBehavior: false,
      cpus: 7,
      sharedPool: true,
      profiling: false,
      isrFlushToDisk: true,
      workerThreads: false,
      pageEnv: false,
      optimizeCss: false,
      nextScriptWorkers: false,
      scrollRestoration: false,
      externalDir: false,
      disableOptimizedLoading: false,
      gzipSize: true,
      swcFileReading: true,
      craCompat: false,
      esmExternals: true,
      appDir: false,
      isrMemoryCacheSize: 52428800,
      serverComponents: false,
      fullySpecified: false,
      outputFileTracingRoot: '',
      swcTraceProfiling: false,
      forceSwcTransforms: false,
      largePageDataBytes: 128000,
      trustHostHeader: false,
    },
    configFileName: 'next.config.js',
  },
});
const handle = nextServer.getRequestHandler();

const server = express();

server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.cspNonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  res.setHeader('Permissions-Policy', 'geolocation=(self)');
  next();
});

server.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        'script-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-eval'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        'style-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:'],
        'object-src': ["'none'"],
        'form-action': ["'none'"],
        'font-src': ["'self'"],
      },
    },
    strictTransportSecurity: {
      maxAge: 31536000,
      preload: true,
    },
  }),
);

server.use(express.static('public'));

server.use(
  '/api/proxy',
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://localhost:3001',
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/api/proxy': '/api/proxy',
    },
    //changeOrigin: true ,
    ws: true,
    onProxyReqWs: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
      let ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
      proxyReq.setHeader('x-forwarded-for', ip);
    },
  }),
);

server.all('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('req.url: ', req.url);
  return handle(req, res);
});

https.createServer(options, server).listen(currentPort, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Failed to start server', err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log('Listening on port', currentPort);
});
```

next.config.js:

```
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone',

  reactStrictMode: false,

  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: 'http://localhost:3001/api/:path*',
      },
    ];
  },
  webpack(config) {
    // Grab the existing rule that handles SVG imports
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.test?.test?.('.svg'));

    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        ...fileLoaderRule,
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        resourceQuery: { not: /svgr/ },
      },

      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        resourceQuery: /svgr/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
    );

    return config;
  },
};
```

What should I change?

I put `.next/standalone/server.js`, the result of the yarn build, on the server,
I ran `node server.js` to start the server and connected to localhost:3000 and got a
I got a 404 error.

I wonder if something has changed in Next14 when building as standalone?